# Why do compilers give a warning about returning a reference to a local stack variable if it is undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, standards

The C++ standard states that returning reference to a local variable (on the stack) is undefined behaviour, so why do many (if not all) of the current compilers *only* give a warning for doing so?

```
struct A{
};

A& foo()
{
    A a;
    return a; //gcc and VS2008 both give this a warning, but not a compiler error
}
```

Would it not be better if compilers give a error instead of warning for this code?

Are there any great advantages to allowing this code to compile with just a warning?

Please note that this is not about a `const` reference which could lengthen the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference itself.

Comment: Not specifically related to this particular warning, but the compiler mostly assumes that if you ignore warnings, you know better than it does. Maybe you happen to know something about the implementation that means although behavior is undefined, you know what's actually going to happen and approve. If you don't think you do know better, you can use `-Werror` to ensure that you never ignore warnings.

Comment: I hope you are not ignoring warnings (like most people do)

Comment: @VJo: that's why I find `-Werror` useful. In a big makefile, it's just about possible to miss a warning going past in a full build, and therefore ignore it accidentally.

Comment: Because there is tons of code out there that does this and has been working fine by accident.  Compiler vendors can't sell updates that break code that is perceived to work.  They'll uninstall the update instead of fixing the bug.

Comment: @Hans: if that is the only reason, then C++0x provides an excellent opportunity for the vendor to do it, since that's *known* to be a breaking change. That old, works-by-accident code could continue to just get a warning when compiled as C++03, whereas code compiled with the new standard could get an error.

Comment: Just notice this from wiki : Undefined behavior is a feature of some programming languages—most famously C.[1]  In these languages, to simplify the specification and allow some flexibility in implementation, the specification leaves the results of certain operations specifically undefined. In general, any behavior afterwards is also undefined. In particular, it is never required that the compiler diagnose undefined behavior — therefore, programs invoking undefined behavior may appear to compile and even run without errors at first, only to fail on another system, or even on another date.

Comment: Making `foo` return a `const A&` would still result in undefined behavior. It would *not* extent the lifetime of the object. That only happens for local const reference types, not const reference return types.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is almost impossible to verify from a compiler point of view whether you are returning a reference to a temporary. If the standard dictated that to be diagnosed as an error, writing a compiler would be almost impossible. Consider:

```
bool not_so_random() { return true; }
int& foo( int x ) {
   static int s = 10;
   int *p = &s;
   if ( !not_so_random() ) {
      p = &x;
   }
   return *p;
}
```

The above program is correct and safe to run, in our current implementation it is guaranteed that `foo` will return a reference to a `static` variable, which is safe. But from a compiler perspective (and with separate compilation in place, where the implementation of `not_so_random()` is not accessible, the compiler cannot know that the program is well-formed.

This is a toy example, but you can imagine similar code, with different return paths, where `p` might refer to different long-lived objects in all paths that return `*p`.

Comment: +1: It is indeed completely impossible to check your example (because the halting problem is unsolvable).

Comment: However there are many cases where it _is_ possible to prove that your program does this and is therefore faulty. Is the fact that you can't always catch the error a good reason for not telling the user they made a mistake when you can?

Comment: @JohnB: An error means a program doesn't compile. For that reason, it's worse to give an error on a correct program than to miss a warning or error on a faulty one.

Comment: @David: +1, Your example above definitely demonstrates a use case where, the compiler cannot determine the UB but I have a doubt Isn't it true that compiler just by seeing the function itself cannot decide the function causes a UB or not because it actually depends on calling code whether the result is a UB or not. Please check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745855/why-its-return-local-variable-on-stack-one-of-c-undefined-behaviour-and-all/6746020#6746020). Does the reasoning hold good?

Comment: @JohnB: That is what warnings are for, and if you compile (I do) with `-Werror`, then that will stop compilation. As of whether it could/should be an error in the cases where it is detected, that has the side effect of creating a false sense of security when the code *compiles* (If it was UB, then the compiler would have caught it!). There is no hard reason not to turn that into an error, but the fact that it would be confusing that you accept/reject code based on your ability to interpret it, rather than a fixed reason.

Comment: +1, David, thanks for the excellent example where compile cannot decide !

Answer (score 10):

Undefined behaviour is not a compilation error, it's just not a well-formed C++ program. Not every ill-formed program is incompilable, it's just un-*predictable*. I'd wager a bet that it's not even possible in principle for a computer to decide whether a given program text is a well-formed C++ program.

You can always add `-Werror` to gcc to make warnings terminate compilation with an error!

To add another favourite SO topic: Would you like `++i++` to cause a compile error, too?

Comment: If the compiler can prove your program yields undefined behavior, it's allowed to fail compilation. (yes I would like `++i++` and `int i; int j = i;` to cause compile error).

Comment: @ybungalobill: Are you sure about that? A compiler should not fail compilation unless the standard says it is allowed to do so.

Comment: Interesting question. I think that `int i; int j = i; j = 4;` should be legal, non? You're never **using** `i` or `j` uninitialized.

Comment: @Jørgen Fogh: The standard allows that: §1.3.12 [defns.undefined]/1 *[...][Note: permissible undefined behavior ranges from [...] to **terminating a translation** or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message)*

Comment: @David Rodrigues: Thanks for the quote. Do you know where the standard describes what happens when you use a stale reference? I think I read somewhere that it only causes undefined behavior when you actually use it, not when you return it.

Comment: Why do you think it's impossible to decide whether a C++ program is well-formed? C++ compilation is only Turing-complete if one assumes no nesting limits to templates, but that notion is explicitly rejected by the standard.

Comment: @Jørgen Fogh: I would look into 3.8 in the standard, that deals with object lifetime. I don't think I can produce a simple quote that refers to *stale* references or pointers... there are different circumstances (for example, after destruction and prior to actual memory release, the properties of the allocated memory and what can be done with *stale* pointers that refer to that location is different than when the memory has been released).

Comment: @MSalters: Look at the example in David Rodriguez's answer. It is impossible to determine in general if `not_so_random()` will ever return. That means that the compiler cannot check if the function ever returns a stale reference.

Comment: @Jørgen Fogh: "_Well formed_" and "_Ill formed_" are specific terms in C++. They describe whether a particular input should be rejected by the compiler, i.e. they're pure compile-time terms. His example is well-formed, yet has _Undefined Behavior_ at runtime.

Comment: @ybu: Actually, `++i++` results in `error: lvalue required as increment operand`, because `++i++` is parsed as `++(i++)`, and `i++` is an rvalue.

Comment: @FredOverflow: For the sake of discussion consider that instead of `++i++` you had `++++i`, or `++i + i++` (choose your poison)

Comment: @MSalters: IMHO, An function will **always** be *"Well formed"*, it is the calling code that causes the *"ill formed"* behavior.

Comment: @Als: Again, no. The Standard defines whether certain code is _ill formed_, and that's a compile-time decision. Arguably, you can't even say something is a function if that part of the code is _ill formed_

Answer (score 8):

*If you return a pointer/reference to a local inside function the **behavior is well defined** as long as you do not dereference the pointer/reference returned from the function.*

***It is an Undefined Behavior only when one derefers the returned pointer.***

Whether it is a Undefined Behavior or not depends on the code calling the function and not the function itself.

So just while compiling the function, the compiler cannot determine if the behavior is Undefined or Well Defined. The best it can do is to warn you of a potential problem and it does!

An Code Sample:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{ 
   int m_i;
   A():m_i(10)
   {

   } 
};  
A& foo() 
{     
    A a;
    a.m_i = 20;     
    return a; 
} 

int main()
{
   foo(); //This is not an Undefined Behavior, return value was never used.

   A ref = foo(); //Still not an Undefined Behavior, return value not yet used.

   std::cout<<ref.m_i; //Undefined Behavior, returned value is used.

   return 0;
}
```

Reference to the C++ Standard:
***section 3.8***

*Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allo-cated 34) or, **after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that refers to the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways.**  Such a pointer refers to allocated storage (3.7.3.2), and using the
pointer as if the pointer were of `type void*`, is well-defined. **Such a pointer may be dereferenced but the resulting lvalue may only be used in limited ways**, as described below.  If the object will be or was of a class type with a non-trivial destructor, and the pointer is used as the operand of a delete-expression, the program has undefined behavior.  If the object will be or was of a non-POD class type, the program has undefined behavior if:*

*—  .......*

Comment: I believe this to be true, but I have not been able to provide a quote from the standard. +1 from me anyway.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: I think the quote from `section 3.8`of the standard can be used as an reference.

Comment: Well, I had already looked at that particular paragraph, but it does not apply here. The *object* has been destructed, **and** the memory has already been given back --which in the particular case of a function level variable with automatic storage happens when the function completes (depending on the calling convention the caller or callee) and the stack frame is dropped. You can argue that the memory was allocated much earlier from the OS, and released much later, but that is an implementation detail, and a different platform/compiler might decide to do otherwise.

Comment: -1, the _storage location_ for local variables does not survive the function return.

Comment: @MSalters: Not debating the downvote, but can you please provide a reference from the standard, I think dreferencing the ill formed/dangling pointer causes Undefined behavior not just holding it.

Comment: Looks like either '98 or '03? Haven't got those available right now, and quoting C++0x would not make sense. The rationale BTW was that there are systems that store pointers in special registers, and having invalid values in them causes UB.

Comment: @MSalters: That is `03`, I have not been able to find quote from the standard that would suggest the above is wrong, Since you are convinced that there is, Can you find and present it here, that would justify your down vote and help us reach a point of agreement on the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Because standard does not restrict us.

If you want to shoot to your own foot you can do it!

However lets see and example where it can be useful:

```
int &foo()
{
    int y;
}

bool stack_grows_forward()
{
    int &p=foo();
    int my_p;
    return &my_p < &p;
}
```

Comment: Where's your function `implementation_uses_stack()`? :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: and for that matter, `comparison_between_unrelated_pointers_works()`.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers should not refuse to compile programs unless the standard says they are allowed to do so. Otherwise it would be much harder to port programs, since they might not compile with a different compiler, even though they comply with the standard.

Consider the following function:

```
int foobar() {
    int a=1,b=0;
    return a/b;
}
```

Any decent compiler will detect that I am dividing by zero, but it should not reject the code since I might actually want to trigger a SIG_FPE signal.

As David Rodríguez has pointed out, there are some cases which are undecidable but there are also some which are not. Some new version of the standard might describe some cases where the compiler must/is allowed to reject programs. That would require the standard to be very specific about the static analysis which is to be performed.

The Java standard actually specifies some rules for checking that non-void methods always return a value. Unfortunately I haven't read enough of the C++ standard to know what the compiler is allowed to do.

Comment: Actually, a common optimization is to replace constant division by multiplication with its inverse, so there are very good reasons to reject this program.

Comment: @MSalters: My point isn't that the program should not be rejected. My point is that only the people who write the standard get to decide that.

Comment: They already decided. See the list of possible results of Undefined Behavior (§1.3.12), of which division by zero is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could also return a reference to a static variable, which would be valid code so the code must be able to compile.

Comment: Hold on, but in the specific case the OP posted, the compiler can see that the variable being returned is non-static.  I think the OP is asking why the compiler allows even such cases.

Comment: @Gravity: Because then the standard would require compilers to diagnose the code to figure out if something was really a temporary. This can be an incredible hard task considering aliasing and separate compilation. Also remember: When the standard was first written, compilers weren't half as smart as they are today.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much super-bad practice to rely on this, but I do believe that in many cases (and that's never a good wager), that memory reference would still be valid if no functions are called between the time `foo()` returns and the time the calling function uses its return value.  In that case, that area of the stack would not have an opportunity to get overwritten.

In C and C++ you can choose to access arbitrary sections of memory anyway (within the process's memory space, of course) via pointer arithmetic, so why not allow the possibility of constructing a reference to wherever one so chooses?